# XPages REST component and authentication

Tags: rest, xpages, lotus-domino

Is it possible that the XPages REST component returns 401 HTTP status code after invalid authentication? Now it returns 200 and the server login page.

My NSF app is used only as a REST service interface to serve the backend application data.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible to do this using an "Override Session Authentication" web rule in the Directory. I believe that that's intended for cordoning off parts of a server like this that shouldn't use session authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Domino 9.0.1 FP10 there is now a notes.ini configuration that forces Domino to return HTTP 401 Unauthorized when serving the login page:

```
DOMINO_FORCE401_WITH_HTML_LOGIN_PAGE=1
```